# Is there a way to stop a hopper minecart while taking items out a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a super smelter in a server and I would like to try to make the hopper minecart automatically stop to feed in items from the chest. Is there a way to do this via Redstone in a way that I could afk it and with a steady supply of items, it automatically stops the cart when empty when below the chest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to modify this Minecraft contraption to make the cart leave if it is full?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383205/is-it-possible-to-modify-this-minecraft-contraption-to-make-the-cart-leave-if-it)